# jq: globbing possible?

Tags: bash, json, jq

I have the following json output:

```
{ x0: { scores: { small, human readable }, payload: { huge data } }
{ x1: ... }
{ x2: ... }
...
{ xn: ... }
```

What I would like to do is, when I finish generating this report, tee it into a file and jq like so, in pseudo code:

```
{json content} | tee out.json | jq '.*.scores'
```

How does one glob like this with jq?

Comment: Could you possibly show valid JSON, and also mention what output you would like to see from your pipeline, given that JSON?

Comment: @Kusalananda  `echo "{"foo":{"scores":1.}}" | jq '.| to_entries | map(.key,.value.scores)'` the output should look like that.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late.  That command in your commend does not work, but if you change the output quotes to single quotes, it produces the JSON document `["foo",1]`.  It still not clear what the input looks like as there is no valid JSON in the question. A shorter expression that seems to do the same thing given your `foo` input is `to_entries[] | [.key, .value.scores]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's odd; used the command below.  I'll double check.  In general (coming from the math dept on this one) more conciseness does not typically mean "better"

Comment: @Kusalananda also, I suppose you would need the version of JQ and the source JSON to evaluate whether my answer "worked"; but the gist of my question is: "Will JQ glob?"

Comment: The `[]` acts like a glob in `to_entries[]` in my example code, which could be written as `to_entries | .[]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda can you explain further? That doesn't look like a glob expression.

Comment: See e.g. [Retrieve nested element with jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647277)

Comment: @Kusalananda why don't you post that answer here, since "Retrieve nested element with jq" is a title that does not describe your answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda either that or mark this a duplicate and link it to that answer so that the phrase "glob" winds up connecting to the answer "`[]` is used like glob's star characters".

Comment: Well, I can't post that answer here as there is no valid JSON document in this question that I could modify the answer to fit. I will mark this as a dupe of the other question though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I suppose I'll do it then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
jq '.| to_entries | map(.key,.value.scores)'
```

This is the answer I came up with, but maybe there is a glob-style way to do it.