# Retrieve nested element with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a list of JSON objects(one object is given below) where the parent element will dynamically be changed ("Oauth2", "Oauth2c"), so that, how can I retrieve a nested level element Ex:- "scopes" from the below without specifying the object path?

```
{
    "Oauth2": {
        "description": "Oauth 2.0 implicit authentication",
        "flows": {
            "implicit": {
                "authorizationUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "scopes": {
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube": "Manage your YouTube account",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator": "See a list of your current active channel members, their current level, and when they became a member",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl": "See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly": "View your YouTube account",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload": "Manage your YouTube videos",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner": "View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit": "View private information of your YouTube channel relevant during the audit process with a YouTube partner"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "oauth2"
    },
    "Oauth2c": {
        "description": "Oauth 2.0 authorizationCode authentication",
        "flows": {
            "authorizationCode": {
                "authorizationUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "scopes": {
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube": "Manage your YouTube account",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator": "See a list of your current active channel members, their current level, and when they became a member",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl": "See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly": "View your YouTube account",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload": "Manage your YouTube videos",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner": "View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit": "View private information of your YouTube channel relevant during the audit process with a YouTube partner"
                },
                "tokenUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
            }
        },
        "type": "oauth2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `jq '..|.scopes?|select(.)' file.json`. Hopefully somebody will answer you with something more idiomatic. I don't because I XXX hate jq ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works when I save the json object to a file. I want it to be worked with a variable. how can I do it? **Ex: jq '..|.scopes?|select(.)' $obj**. Actually,  I have .yaml file and working with library niet ([Link] https://github.com/openuado/niet) to extract the elements from shell

Comment: `echo null | jq "$obj | ..|.scopes?|select(.)"` where `$obj` contains the json data. Again, there probably is a less obtuse way of doing it ;-)

Comment: :-) What is the meaning of putting null here?

Comment: afaicg `jq` won't go without an object to apply the "filter" on. You can put `{"foo":"bar"}` or `[{},{}]` instead of `null`, it makes no differrence. The `jq` on my phone also does with `jq -n "$obj | ..|.scopes?|select(.)"`, though I have no idea if that works on older versions too.

Comment: @user414777, Thank you very much for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `scopes` objects in your example data are accessible through the `jq` expression

```
.[].flows[].scopes
```

The `[]` acts as a sort of path wildcard. Or rather, it gives you each of the object's parts.

Given your example data:

```
$ jq '.[].flows[].scopes' file.json
{
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube": "Manage your YouTube account",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator": "See a list of your current active channel members, their current level, and when they became a member",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl": "See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly": "View your YouTube account",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload": "Manage your YouTube videos",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner": "View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit": "View private information of your YouTube channel relevant during the audit process with a YouTube partner"
}
{
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube": "Manage your YouTube account",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator": "See a list of your current active channel members, their current level, and when they became a member",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl": "See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly": "View your YouTube account",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload": "Manage your YouTube videos",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner": "View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit": "View private information of your YouTube channel relevant during the audit process with a YouTube partner"
}
```

You could also use

```bsh
jq '.. | select(.scopes?).scopes' file.json
```

which gives you the same output as above for your example document.  This searches for anything with a `scopes` key in it, and then extracts the contents of that key.

Older releases of `jq` possibly need to use

```bsh
jq '.. | select(type == "object" and has("scopes")).scopes' file.json
```